# Calling a managed static class (in C#) from C++ CLI (.NET)

Tags: .net, c++-cli, clr

I have a header file in **C++ CLI** (Game.h) which initializes a property (MAGIC_SEA) by using a DLL in **C#** (settings.dll). However, when I build this code (with CLR support) throws the following error:

```
Error   3   error C3083: 'game_id': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type c:\users\ed\projectS\Game.h 
Error   4   error C2039: 'MAGIC_SEA' : is not a member of 'settings'    c:\users\ed\ed\ProjectSl\Game.h
```

**Game.h**

```
...
using namespace settings;
...
const short MAGIC_SEA = settings::game_id::MAGIC_SEA;
...
```

**settings.dll**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Resources;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Management;
using System.Management.Instrumentation;

namespace settings {
...
public static class game_id {

      public const short MAGIC_SEA = 1;
...
      }    
}
```

Comment: The compile error is pretty plain, "settings" is a namespace name, not a type name.  So the compiler does not yet know what "game_id" means.  What "static class" might mean is hard to guess, this just doesn't have anything to do with valid C++/CLI code.  A variable declaration must always appear inside a ref class, the equivalent of a const is `literal`.

Comment: Hans, yes, "settings" is a namespace, but I do not  seem to get that of "the compiler does not yet know what game_id means.

Comment: C++ uses a single-pass compilation model.  A declaration must always appear before a definition and usage.  This is very unlike C#.  Having a working knowledge of C++ is pretty important to have a shot at writing correct C++/CLI code.  And posting recognizable code important to get an SO answer.  Consider getting help from a team member.

Comment: Ok. I will do. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the C++/CLI project isn't correctly referencing the C# library.  Without a reference, the C++ compiler won't be able to find any of the classes declared in C#.

Depending on Visual Studio version, the steps to add references in a C++/CLI project can be rather different than other .NET languages, which show references inside the Solution Explorer tree.  In C++/CLI projects in older Visual Studio versions, you'll find them with the compile options instead:

[image]